# How do you instantiate an Entity Framework DBContext in a .Net Console Application?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am declaring a `DBContext` variable like this in my program:

```
class Program
{
    static MyDataContext context;

    // ...
}
```

but I get the following error:

> The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.

My connection string in `App.Config` has the same name as the `DBContext` variable and works from a web app. Has anyone else seen this?

And if I instantiate all in one line like this:

```
class Program
{
    static MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext();

    // ...
}
```

instead of in main:

```
context = MyDataContext();
```

I get this error:

> The type initializer for 'NLP.Program' threw an exception.

Comment: Is there a reason that the `DbContext` is static?

Comment: is MyDataContext your own custom class or does it come from EF? Because if you don't have a typo, it seems as if it was a function and not a class (`context = MyDataContext();`)

Comment: Check the InnerException - type initializer exception usually means an error in a static constructor.  Based on that error there's likely a missing app.config value.

Answer (score -1):

Avoid using a context this way and prefer to adhere to `using` for disposable resources:

```
using(MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext(...))
{
    // ...
}
```

This does not solve your problem but is a first step to better code.

EDIT: removed simply wrong answer. Better no answer than a wrong one...

Comment: Does not answer the question however.